# Fullscreen Activity issue in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I updated to 4.3 today and I saw that fullscreen activities are not working properly, more in details, the top bar is always shown.

I tried to run on the emulator (4.2) and works fine.

Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: can put some code or menifest file that can tell you something.

Comment: 4.3 is latest than 4.2(jelly bean)....so sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by two ways

1) Programatically :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

2) Modifying `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
```

**NOTE:** Don't you think it's better to use a single line for attaining the desired task, rather than duplicating the a long code again and again in all the activities?!

Comment: Changed theme from @style/FullscreenTheme to @android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen

Comment: **NOTE:** Don't you think it's better to use a single line for attaining the desired task, rather than duplicating the a long code again and again in all the activities?!